# Passing values between form and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view with many controls (50+) each connected a scope controller object using ng-model, yet I must move the content of inventory object to another object dataObj before posting the data to the api endpoint. Problem I am facing is that when any of the field is left empty it is not moved with object 'inventory' to the controller, thus when I transfer data between 'inventory' and 'dataObj' I get undefined, so I made a little check on data received in the inventory object as shown below but I don't think that this is the best approach, so I was hoping for some advice on best approach to check on the 'inventory' object fields to make sure if they exist or not before moving them to the 'dataObj' object. Thanks

1. Form (part):

   ```
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Price USD</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="priceUSD" id="gps" placeholder="priceUSD" ng-model="inventory.prices.usd">
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Price GBP</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="priceGBP" id="priceGBP" placeholder="priceGBP" ng-model="inventory.prices.gbp">
       </div>
   ```
2. JS

   ```
         typeof inventory.prices.gbp === 'undefined'? dataObj.PRICES.gbp = '' : dataObj.PRICES.gbp = inventory.prices.gbp;
   ```

Comment: I think that, if a field is empty, you shouldn't send it to your API at all. It may be the API role to check if data is available and react accordingly. For the JS part you wrote, you can simplify it by writing `dataObj.PRICES.gbp = inventory.prices.gbp || '';`

Comment: Isn't it possible to have some default value for your model? So it will not have 'undefined' at all?